# Create action with nested attributes using Ember.js, Ember-data.js and Rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, transactions, ember.js, ember-data, nested-attributes

I'm working on a project management website. I'm using Ember.js, Ember-data.js and a Rails backend. By now, I populated the backend database with some test data. I can do `show` and `index` operations on them working quite good, and get the nested attributes too. The next thing is build the `create` operation on one of them. I've decided to start with `Project`, whose model implementations are:

## PROJECT.JS

```
App.Adapter.map
(
  'App.Project',
  {
    creator: {embedded: 'always'},
    coworkers: {embedded: 'always'}
  }
);


App.Project = DS.Model.extend
(
   {
      title: DS.attr('string'),
      creator: DS.belongsTo('App.Person', {embedded: 'always'}),
      coworkers: DS.hasMany('App.Person', {embedded: 'always'}),
      startingDate: DS.attr('string'),
      endingDate: DS.attr('string'),
      description: DS.attr('string')
   }
);
```

## PROJECT.RB

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: projects
#
#  id            :integer          not null, primary key
#  title         :string(255)
#  starting_date :date
#  ending_date   :date
#  description   :string(255)
#  creator_id    :integer
#  created_at    :datetime         not null
#  updated_at    :datetime         not null

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :title, :startingDate, :endingDate, :description, :creator_id
  validates :title, presence: true

  ####################################################################
  ## ONE-TO-MANY RELATION FOR CREATOR                               ##
  ####################################################################
  belongs_to :creator,
    foreign_key: "creator_id",
    class_name: "Person"

  ####################################################################
  ## MANY-TO-MANY RELATION FOR COWORKERS - JOIN TABLE: PROJECT_TEAM ##
  ####################################################################
  has_many :project_teams,
    foreign_key: "project_id",
    class_name: "ProjectTeam"
  has_many :coworkers,
    through: :project_teams
end
```

## PROJECT_CONTROLLER.RB

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  # GET /project.json
  def index
    render json: Project.all
  end

  # GET /projects/1.json
  def show
    p = Project.find(params[:id])
    render json: p
  end

  # POST /projects.json
  def create
    p = Project.new(params[:project])
    p.save!
    p.reload
  end
end
```

## PROJECT_SERIALIZER.RB

```
class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id,
             :title,
             :starting_date,
             :ending_date,
             :description,
             :creator_id

  has_many :coworkers, embed: :id
end
```

And the action that I'm trying to figure out to `create` the project on Ember is this one:

## PROJECT_NEW_CONTROLLER.JS

```
App.ProjectsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
(
  {
    needs: ['app'],
    projectTitle: null,
    startingDate: null,
    endingDate: null,
    description: null,

    createProject: function()
    {
      var pTitle =        this.get('projectTitle');
      var pStartingDate = this.get('startingDate');
      var pEndingDate =   this.get('endingDate');
      var pDescription =  this.get('description');

      var personId = this.get('controllers.app.personId');

      this.transaction = this.get('store').transaction();

      var newProject = this.transaction.createRecord
      (
        App.Project,
        {
          title: pTitle,
          startingDate: pStartingDate,
          endingDate: pEndingDate,
          description: pDescription,
          creator_id: parseInt(personId, 10)
        }
      );

      this.set('model', newProject);

      this.transaction.commit();
      this.transaction = null;
    }
  }
);
```

By now, the standard attributes are working great. But I can't get working the `creator_id` attribute and even less the `coworkers` array attribute. The maximum approximation I've got, found out using Firebug, is to check that my attributes are correctly being assigned into `this.transaction`:

```
this.transaction.records.list[0].get('title')           "Project title"
this.transaction.records.list[0].get('startingDate')    "17/07/2013"
this.transaction.records.list[0].get('creator_id')      1
...
```

But my JSON post is like this:

```
{
    "project": 
    {
        "title": "Project title",
        "starting_date": "17/07/2013",
        "ending_date": "30/08/2013",
        "description": "A brief description",
        "creator_id": null
    }
}
```

I've been searching how to use `transactions` and `createRecord` methods, but I haven't found any kind of guide or documentation, I'm using them just following some codes I've found here or on [this great Ember Data Example from Dan Gebhardt](https://github.com/dgeb/ember_data_example). So, summarising, my questions are:

1. How `transactions` and `createRecord` functions work
2. How to insert an id attribute for a `belongs_to` relationship on a `create` transaction (`creator_id` attribute)
3. How to insert a set of id attributes from a `has_many` relationship on a `create` transaction (`coworkers` attribute)

I'd really appreciate some help on this. Thanks a lot in advance.